# Extend solution of ODE by parity

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Suppose you have a set $A=A^+\cup A^-\subset\mathbb{R}$, with $A^\pm$ connected and reciprocally symmetric w.r.t. $0$, i.e. $-A^\pm=A^\mp$ (for example $A=(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,+\infty)$) and an even function $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the following ODE:
$$
xf''(x)=f'(x)\qquad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}.
$$
Is it possible to extend continuously the solution to all $\mathbb{R}$?
Maybe this is a very particular case, because the solution of the ODE on every connected component is $f(x)=a_0+a_1x^2$, $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$. So assume that
$$
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
a_0+a_1x^2\qquad x\in A^+\\
b_0+b_1x^2\qquad x\in A^-.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Now, imposing parity on $f$ it holds $a_0=b_0$ and $a_1=b_1$, so one can define $$f(x)=a_0+a_1x^2,\qquad\forall x\in\mathbb{R},$$ and $f$ is extended continuously (even differentiably) on all $\mathbb{R}$.
Is it correct? Is it something standard? Is it something I can deduce from the ODE itself?
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered the question yourself regarding this particular differential equation.  But in general, given a differential equation and an even solution of it on $A$, there is no guarantee that it can be extended to a solution  outside of $A$.  For example, it might be that if you try to extend the solution you could run into a singularity somewhere.

[EDIT]  Example: change your differential equation to $x f''(x) + 3 f'(x) = 0$, and you have solutions $f(x) = a + b x^{-2}$ that are even but (for $b \ne 0$) have poles at $x=0$.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.

Comment: Is it something I can deduce from the ODE if it is extendable or not?

Comment: For a second-order linear equation $p(x) f''(x) + q(x) f'(x) + r(x) f(x) = g(x)$, if $p, q, r, g$ are continuous, the only possible obstacles are zeros of $p(x)$.  Those might be analyzed using the Frobenius theory of regular singular points.